# Get Date Time value in format 2021-11-03T22:45:00+05:30

Tags: apex, datetime

I'm need to pass datetime value in 2021-11-03T22:45:00+05:30 format to external system. But I'm not sure how to get datetime in this format.

I tried multiple things, but it's not returning in this format.

```
system.debug('Created Date is ' + string.valueOfGmt(acc.CreatedDate));  
//system.debug('Created Date is ' + acc.CreatedDate.format('YYYY-MM-ddThh:mm:ss')); // this gives error.
```

Answer (score 2):

`T` part is not processed in `format()`, you need to exclude in from function params (or escape it like `\'T\'` as @Derek F mentioned). Also you'll need to use `HH` instead of `hh` if you do not specify `AM/PM` part ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)). `XXX` is stand for time zone in format `-08:00`.

```
System.debug('Created Date is ' + acc.CreatedDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ssXXX'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Apex borrows [Java's SimpleDate format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The `YYYY-MM-ddThh:mm:ss` part is almost correct, you just need to escape the 'T', and add the bit for the time zone, which according to Java's documentation you should add 'XXX' (which should give you the sign, two digit hour, colon, and two digit minutes)

`'YYYY-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ssXXX'` is what you're looking for

Comment: It is not correct, `T` is not a part of Date and Time Patterns, you'll need to separate formatting in two different parts to pass `T` as part of String.

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova Yep,  I should have tried it myself before posting. I have made a correction.

Comment: This is also `HH` and `XXX`, because `XX` will show result without colon)